# ¿Cómo ocultar las respuestas HTTP en Angular?

Tags: angular, http

Estoy haciendo una conexión a una API. Pero quiero saber si hay una forma de ocultar las respuestas HTTP, pues ya que no quiero mostro el link de mi API.

**Quiero una forma de ocultar este error:**
[image: Este es el error que deseo ocultar]
En este archivo hago las respectivas conexiones con la base de datos > connection.services.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { LevelCheckI } from '../auth/interfaces/level-check-i';
import { LevelCheckResponceI } from '../auth/interfaces/level-check-responce-i';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnectionService {
  public respoce:boolean = false;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  checkAnswer(levelCheck:LevelCheckI): Observable<LevelCheckResponceI>{
    let level = levelCheck.level;
    let resp = levelCheck.correct_responce;
    let json = `[{"level":${level},"correct_responce":"${resp}"}]`
    return this.httpClient.patch<LevelCheckResponceI>(`${this.LINK_SERVER}/level/check-answer`, json).
    pipe(tap((res: LevelCheckResponceI)=>{
      if(res){
        this.respoce = true;
      }else{
        this.respoce = false;
      }
    })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente no es posible ocultar las peticiones/respuestas que se hacen desde el cliente. Si lo que te molesta es el error y simplemente lo quieres ocultar para ti, lo puedes hacer desmarcando el filtro de errores donde pone "Niveles predeterminados". Si lo que quieres solucionar el error 409 que te está dando tienes que ver por qué tu petición PATCH no te la está admitiendo el backend. ¿Es posible que no estés pasando el identificador de la entidad Answer? SI no pasas un identificador el backend puede que no sepa que respuesta quieres modificar y por eso te de 409 Conflict.

Comment: Por otro lado me extraña que checkAnswer use el metodo PATCH, me sonaría más que debería ser GET ¿no? ¿qué se supone que hace el backend cuando se llama a check-answer?

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA Si eso lo imagine, pero lo que solo quiero ocultar el error para todo el que se conecte, o quitar el error muestre link de la API, se que si alguien quisiera ver todas las conexiones que hago en mi web, inclusive a la API lo haría. Sobre el error, se que si, porque programe mi API para que responda un 409 cuando no se encuentra en la base de datos.

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA  Si, lo intente, pero no se como enviar el body con el método "this.httpClient.get", pero no me permite enviar mi body asi:  this.httpClient.get<LevelCheckResponceI>(`${this.LINK_SERVER}/level/check-answer`, json).

Comment: el error te sale en la consola porque no controlas el error que da la api. Puedes hacer el catch del error para que no te salga en la consola.

Comment: @hawks Mmmm siii, creo que eso tiene que funcionar. Lo intentare.

Comment: @hawks eh... ¿Dónde específicamente pongo el TryCatch? lo intente poniendo el return dentro del TryCatch... y continua saliendo :(

Comment: @IsaacMartinez puedes basarte en este artículo https://www.positronx.io/angular-error-handling-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: @hawks... Si funciona, pero el error se sigue mostrando. Intente buscar el archivo que muestra el error para quitar el `console.error()` pero no logre encontrarlo. Lo que hare es enviar una respuesta 200 desde mi API pero con un mensaje de error. IGUAL MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS.

Comment: si lo has hecho tal cual esta en el artículo en el metodo `handleError` tambien tienes un `console.error`